# VM guest cloning

Tags: vmware-esx, cloning

I am able to make a copy of my existing VM guest folder and another folder on my datasource (trying to clone this vm to a new vm). However, I can't seem to add a way to add it to the inventory so that I could start it up. Any suggestion on this matter?

I'm using ESX4

Thanks

David.

Answer (score 2):

This should be enough:

1. Open the vSphere Client
2. Open the Datastore browser

   - Select the Server in the main tree
   - Select "Configuration" Tab
   - Select "Storage"
   - Right click on the datastore and select "Browse Datastore"
3. Browse to your newly copied folder
4. Right click on the ".vmx" file and select "Add to Invetory"

Hope this helps :)